# Deriving Encodable trait in a module not working

Tags: rust

I have a `main.rs` file and a `logging` module inside `logging.rs` file. My file layout is:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── logging.rs
│   └── main.rs
```

The contents of my `main.rs`

```
mod logging;
fn main(){}
```

The contents of `logging.rs`

```
extern crate serialize;

use self::serialize::{json, Encoder, Encodable};

#[deriving(Encodable)]
pub struct Person {
  pub age: i32
}
```

However this does not compile. The error is:

```
error: failed to resolve. Did you mean `self::serialize`?
/Users/valentin/../src/logging.rs:7 #[deriving(Encodable)]
```

Three questions:

1. Why does not it compile?
2. Why does moving the struct and use directive to main.rs makes it compile?
3. Why does changing `serialize::Encodable` to `Show` trait makes it compile even inside `logging` module?

**However**
If I add

```
extern crate serialize;

use self::serialize::{json, Encoder, Encodable};
```

to `main.rs`, it all starts compiling.

This is very confusing, the fourth questions is why isn't it sufficient to have only one extern crate + use serialize::.. inside logging module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s look at the code that’s generated, with `rustc main.rs --pretty expanded`:

```
#![feature(phase)]
#![no_std]
#![feature(globs)]
#[phase(plugin, link)]
extern crate std = "std";
extern crate rt = "native";
use std::prelude::*;
mod logging {
    extern crate serialize;
    use std::prelude::*;

    use self::serialize::{json, Encoder, Encodable};

    pub struct Person {
        pub age: i32,
    }
    #[automatically_derived]
    impl <__S: ::serialize::Encoder<__E>, __E>
         ::serialize::Encodable<__S, __E> for Person {
        fn encode(&self, __arg_0: &mut __S) ->
         ::std::result::Result<(), __E> {
            match *self {
                Person { age: ref __self_0_0 } =>
                __arg_0.emit_struct("Person", 1u, |_e| {
                                    return _e.emit_struct_field("age", 0u,
                                                                |_e|
                                                                    (*__self_0_0).encode(_e));
                                }),
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() { }
```

This demonstrates that the `#[deriving(Encodable)]`expands to stuff involving the paths `::serialize::*`; that is, the item `serialize` *from the crate root*.

Now, `extern crate serialize;` from inside `mod logging` means that the path to `serialize` is `::logging::serialize`, which is also accessible as `self::serialize` inside the module; there is no `::serialize`.

The solution is moving the `extern crate serialize;` into the crate root. (This is where all `extern crate` definitions should be.) This is what fixed it for you, not the `use self::serialize::{json, Encoder, Encodable};`.

Comment: Thanks for answering all my questions with a piece of code, that's nice)